# How do Dojo ValidationTextArea widgets get highlighted when invalid?

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo, widget

I am trying to create a custom Dojo ValidationIdBox widget that inherits from ValidationTextBox. My custom widget will add async duplicate ID checking with a back-end server.

I sub-classed dijit.form.ValidationTextBox and modified two methods: isValid() and validate(). However, I can't get the validation to fully work. The widget catches and highlights problems like missing required input. It even catches when there is a duplicate ID (the tooltip appears), but it fails to highlight the field as expected.

I have tried to isolate my problem with a simplified code snippet below. It is mostly the origininal Dojo code with some minor modifications. My general strategy is to let the widget validate as a regular ValidationTextBox, then test for a duplicate ID. I modified isValid() to have two modes: plain validation and validation with uniqueness check. Currently, the uniqueness test intentionally always fails.

In a similar fashion, I modified validate() to do its normal thing, then do some additional processing if normal validation succeeds but the validation with uniqueness test fails. I tried to mirror the same logic as when the ValidationTextBox is in an `error` state, but the same effects are not mirrored: The 'ID not available' tooltip appears, but the red outline with exclamation mark does not appear.

I examined [ValidationTextBox's code](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.2/dojo-release-1.7.2/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox.js), but I cannot figure out how that special styling is triggered... **can someone explain how ValidationTextArea works?** Specifically I'm not quite sure how `this._maskValidSubsetError`, `aria-invalid`, and `this.state` are used.

(Also sometimes, I want the tooltip to appear, but not the red styling. Like to show when AJAX duplicate ID check request is processing.)

```
// If ValidationTextBoxValidates
isValid: function(isFocused, requireUnique) {
    if (typeof requireUnique === 'undefined') requireUnique = false;

    var isValid = this.inherited(arguments);
    var isUnique = false;

    return (requireUnique ? (isValid && isUnique) : isValid);
},

validate: function(/*Boolean*/ isFocused){
    // summary:
    //        Called by oninit, onblur, and onkeypress.
    // description:
    //        Show missing or invalid messages if appropriate, and highlight textbox field.
    // tags:
    //        protected
    var message = "";
    var isValid = this.disabled || this.isValid(isFocused);
    if(isValid){ this._maskValidSubsetError = true; }
    var isEmpty = this._isEmpty(this.textbox.value);
    var isValidSubset = !isValid && isFocused && this._isValidSubset();
    this._set("state", isValid ? "" : (((((!this._hasBeenBlurred || isFocused) && isEmpty) || isValidSubset) && this._maskValidSubsetError) ? "Incomplete" : "Error"));
    this.focusNode.setAttribute("aria-invalid", isValid ? "false" : "true");

    if(this.state == "Error"){
        this._maskValidSubsetError = isFocused && isValidSubset; // we want the error to show up after a blur and refocus
        message = this.getErrorMessage(isFocused);
    }else if(this.state == "Incomplete"){
        message = this.getPromptMessage(isFocused); // show the prompt whenever the value is not yet complete
        this._maskValidSubsetError = !this._hasBeenBlurred || isFocused; // no Incomplete warnings while focused
    }else if(isEmpty){
        message = this.getPromptMessage(isFocused); // show the prompt whenever there's no error and no text
    }

    /// Begin custom widget code
    if (isValid && !this.isValid(isFocused, true) ) {
        isValid = false;

        var isValidSubset = !isValid && isFocused && this._isValidSubset();

        this._maskValidSubsetError = isFocused && isValidSubset; // we want the error to show up after a blur and refocus
        message = 'ID not available';

        this.focusNode.setAttribute("aria-invalid", isValid ? "false" : "true");
    }
    /// End custom widget code

    this.set("message", message);
    return isValid;
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

might be missing the obvious, hidden amongst a cloud of inline &&|| ;)))))

The point in the blur/keypress mechanism is that the tooltip will only be visible on the box that is currently shown, hence _maskValid

Have you tried `this.set("state", this.isUnique() ? "" : "Error");` ??

Widgets are Stateful and the .set might just do the trick, firing an event or publish a topic

Comment: `this._set("state", "Error")` enables the red validation border.

Comment: then this._set("state", "") should remove it right? ""I cannot figure out how that special styling is triggered"" Not sure what youre asking specifically. However, i can tell you that the aria/wairole should not be your concern - is good custom to uphold, but its only for accessibility and screen readers, not at all related to styles

Comment: however. as you probably know, the 'red validation border' is visible on validation errors, then - when the box receives focus a `Tooltip` is presented (message) which in addition is set in the `missingMessage` and `invalidMessage` - this is the purpose of maskValidSubsetError; to know how to react `onFocus`